# Why don't i have access to the element here (jQuery plugin)

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, object, plugins

I am trying a new way to write a jQuery plugin.

```
var $detailbox = $('.detailBox') ;

TargetList.init($detailbox);
```

**TargetList:**

```
TargetList = {

    init: function (elem) {

        console.log($(elem));

    }
};
```

elem will return:

```
[section#detailBox. detailBox, selector: ".detailBox", context: document, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

First question: What is this?

Second, and more important question: Why will `element.id` return undefined?

My guess is that i can't simply pass n object to the `init()` method and expect that i have control over it?
But how can i do this, assuming that i want to keep that structure?

Comment: Stick with tried & tested plugin patterns. You are unlikely to better them.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot

I agree, but i wasted  the past 48hours with testing a bunch of patterns, unliking almost all of them.

I found that pattern here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/my-current-javascript-design-pattern/

which maybe is not exactly a plugin pattern, but what else?

I like it's syntax and i guess it's easier for me to work with than the pattern from the official guide. Am i missing something bad, which should prevent me from using this?

Thanks for your opinion on the topic anyway, i am grateful for everything as this bothers me really hard.

Comment: Sprottenwels, maybe there's more to your code than what's in the question but as it stands there's no evidence of a jQuery plugin. Not liking the patterns you have found isn't going to help you. Forget "like", think "learn". You are not going to guess a plugin into existence.

Comment: What i am trying to do is, writing a plugin, a self-created functionality, by using the so-called module pattern. So, i am not trying to implement my own way to solve this problem but rather searching for a comfortable yet "tried and tested" way. I guess that topic is full off personal taste. And this is what makes it incredibly hard for me as a bloody novice, to actually get something  done, rather than reading dozens of opinions of HOW to get things done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logged object is the `jQuery Object`

For the second question , `id is not a method of jQuery`.It is an property of a `DOM object` .

So try this

`$(elem)[0].id`   **or** `$(elem).attr('id')`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Is it possible to simplify this, it seems a little bit messy to me, tzhat i have to go through attr() everytime.

Comment: Using the index after the element will convert the `jQuery object` to a `DOM object` which will expose the properties of the object . So you can directly reference the element with the property of the element.  So `$(elem)[0].id`

Answer (score 1):

`console.log($(elem));` this simply print jquery object on console.

and looking at this :

```
[section#detailBox. detailBox, selector: ".detailBox", context: document, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

show's that You passed your element to `init` successfully

**Accessing ID :**

Try

```
$(elem).attr('id');
```

Comment: Can i pass the DOM object too, for better access to it's attributes?